# How do I find out in Python if coreutils version 8.24 or higher is installed?

Tags: python, linux

There is a feature for monitoring the progress of dd with coreutils 8.24

(See also : 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd/539305)

This means, I can can call shell commandos such as

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress
```

How can I ensure that the right coreutils version is installed on the host system while I execute the above specified command?

As this line is part of a python application may run on different distributions, a verification with the package managers is not the best way forward. Also we cannot verify the existence of an installed library with an `which` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) since `dd` provides a `--version` flag to output it's version:

```
import subprocess

m = subprocess.check_output(["dd", "--version"])
ver_line = m.split('\n')[0]
ver = ver_line.split(' ')
msg = 'dd status=progress does not work'
if float(ver[2]) >= 8.24:
    msg = 'dd status=progress works'
print msg
```

might be a good enough version check.

I don't think your sample `dd` command is the one you really want.